# AWS EC2 Amazon Linux 2023: Installing PHP 7.4

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I cannot seem to be able to find php7.4 as a package on Amazon Linux 2023.

The latest version is PHP 8.1 but the application I'm using has compatibility issues with the latest version of PHP; hence need to downgrade.

Is it possible for someone to guide me please?

Thank you!

Comment: "I cannot seem to be able to find php7.4" where did you look?

Answer (score 1):

[PHP 7 is EOL](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). If your application has "compatibility issues", fix them.

Comment: Easier said than done, when you have a code base with over 14,000 required fix.

Comment: If your question is "how do I run PHP code safely that requires me to use an EOL version of PHP" the answer is you cant. How you would achieve it technically is another matter, but this is a band-aid that resolves nothing. You could for example try installing the application in a container/vm either on a newer OS level where you manually grab php and set it up from https://www.php.net/releases/index.php -- or use an older OS version where it's included as a package. Still, everyone should be aware of the security implications of doing this.

Comment: As far as I can see, that wasn't OP's question - it's one you made up to answer instead. If they need to deploy a v7.4 application then there's nothing wrong with asking for help to acheive that.

Comment: @charliefortune yes there is, just like it would be wrong to deploy a production server running ubuntu 16